# Forcing refresh of a background image

Tags: css

Is there a way to make sure that a certain background image recently updated does appear in its last version on everybody's browser (rather than the old version stored in cache)?

It has to be a solution not involving touching the line of code calling the CSS (I could put a question mark and a version number after the css file name, like : `<link href="styles.css?v=2" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`, but in this case I don't have access to this part of the code)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use the following approach:

```
.button {
    background: url(../Images/button.png?v=1234);
}
```

Comment: He means to use a random number in query string. Do u know how?

Comment: Cannot you use javascript to generate the random number for you?

Comment: one question: if i add "?=..." tag, then i upload it to my site, (after the refresh) should i  delete  "?=..." from URL?

Comment: @BenceUszkai You forgot a v. It says `?v=`, not `?=`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add another CSS rule after the other CSS, that overrides the rules that loads the image and uses an image with an added version number.

CSS rules loaded later have higher priority, so you can use the same selector as in the main CSS, and it will override it.

If you can't do that, then you are screwed. You have to change the URL of the image that is loaded to surely get the new image.

Answer (score 1):

Few things i like to put here

1. Images, JS, CSS files referred in HTML pages are cached in browser based on the URL
2. Change in URL will issue a new request to server and store the latest in cache.

All you need to do is Change URL .

Though you modified css style sheet, you need to update HTML for CSS reference.

```
background: url(../Images/button.png?v=1234);
```

Ex: 
    `http://www.site.com/css/style.css` to `http://www.site.com/css/style.css?ver=002`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?ver=002" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `Expires` in `htaccess`, but If the image is really large then I would advise against this. As you ask without CSS, try:

```
<Files "your_bg.jpg">
FileETag None
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</Files>
```